# UIDatePicker to display day of week shortname - Custom UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, uipickerview

I am reasonably new to both iOS development and stackoverflow so apologies in advance.

I would like to use a datepicker that shows the Day of Week shortname as part of the first (day) column in the picker. I ultimately would like a picker that is formatted:

"Mon 7" | "Sept" | "2015"

Almost a combination of standard date and the dateandtime mode of the UIDatePicker.

When researching online the only solution seems to be to create a custom UIPickerView but I have no idea how to do this. Does anyone know of anywhere I can find an example of this?

So essentially my question is broken down in to two parts:

- How do I 'duplicate' the logic of the UIDatePicker in a UIPickerView passing in a minimum date (today) and a maximum date (for example "12/12/2017").
- How do I then display the day column in my desired format.

These two posts seem to explain the latter part of my query but I'm unsure how to get to that stage.

[Custom DatePicker using UIPIckerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401805/custom-datepicker-using-uipickerview)

[Generating Date Logic for UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401045/generating-date-logic-for-uipickerview)

Thank you in advance for your assistance - my app is being written in objective-c if that is of any use.

Comment: Keep in mind that this approach will have funky UX, as changing the month would require reloading the first column (as days of the week will match different numbered dates for each month). Speaking from a usability standpoint, I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You seem to know most of what you need to do. Narrow your question down to a specific implementation issue you are having. Update your question with your attempted code and point out a specific issue you are having. If you haven't tried anything yet, then you should first give it a try.